# Skip the middle parameter for multiple options route parameters in express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

So this example

```
app.get('/articles/:year?/:month?/:day?', function(req, res) {
  var year = req.params.year; //either a value or undefined
  var month = req.params.month;
  var day = req.params.day;
}
```

my understanding is it takes:

1. year only
2. year, month (if 2 parameters)
3. year, month, day (if there're 3 parameters)

The question is, how to do year and day only ?
can you do this
app.get('/articles/1999//3') ?

Comment: It works as is. only that day or month will be undefined if you leave it out

Comment: you mean this will actually work ? ('/articles/1999//3'), yes if month is undefined, that's what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array to declare your route's pathes :

```
app.get(['/articles/:year/:month/:day', '/articles/:year/:day'], function(req, res) {
  var year = req.params.year; //either a value or undefined
  var month = req.params.month;
  var day = req.params.day;
}
```

Comment: i need case 2 as well, '/articles/:year/:month', that's why i need a blank parameter if month is skipped, can ('/articles/1999//3') work ?